# bootstrap nav centering link

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, navigation

I'm the worst stylist in the world, so let's get that out right off.

I'm having a terrible time figuring out the right classes to get the first action link centered (more or less) on the page.  I've tried variations on my first ul like col-sm-6 and text-right, to no avail.  Some pull-right action, that's not what I want.

```
    <div id="bootstrapSOLmenu" class="navbar navbar-default">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="navbar-collapse collapse">
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                    <li>@Html.ActionLink("Online Claim Center", "", "Claim")</li>
                </ul>
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                    <li>@Html.ActionLink("FAQ", "FAQ", "Claim")</li>
                    <li>
                        @Html.ActionLink("Help", "", null, new { href = "javascript:HelpPopup.Show();" })
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

So, what I'm looking for is to get the "Online Claim Center" link centered on the page, and have the FAQ/Help links off to the right (but on the same vertical plane).

I was thinking col-sm-6 and text-right to make the ul take up half the page, and shove the link over there, but that's not working out--the link stays left justified.

Comment: I was able to hack it together by preceding my first ul with `<div class="col-sm-5"> </div>`, but even _I_ know that's a hack.  Good enough for beta, still hoping some good stylist can help me get it _right_.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not fully sure if this is what you're looking for.

Using "justify-content-between", margins, and column classes I was able to center one link on the page within one ul. This requires a "col-5" and "col-7" div as well as ul class="w-100".

```
<nav class="navbar" navbar-expand-lg" justify-content-between">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="col-5">
           <!-- Brand / Logo -->
        </div>

        <div id="nav" class="collapse navbar-collapse col-7">
            <ul class="navbar-nav w-100>
                <li class="nav-item mr-auto"> <!-- Margin Right Pushes Link To Far Right -->
                   Online Claim Center
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">FAQ</li>
                <li class="nav-item">Help</li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</nav>
```

**You can remove content from the col-5 div if you would like.

https://codepen.io/wheel58m/pen/xxwyKGg[CodePen](https://codepen.io/wheel58m/pen/xxwyKGg)

Comment: Thank you for the idea.  I don't see that the mr-auto styling is recognized in my app.  Guessing we're using some frightfully out-of-date styles or something.  I'll keep fiddling around.

Comment: mr-auto is just "margin-right: auto" in your css. You can assign that in your css if the class isn't working.